# Subtracting one ArrayList form another performance

Tags: performance, optimization, groovy, collections

I want to subtract one ArrayList from another

```
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
class Person
{
    PersonGender gender
    String name
    String surname
}

static def substractList(ArrayList<Person> listOne, ArrayList<Person> listTwo) {
    listOne.minus listTwo
    // listOne has 200k elements
    // listTwo has 170k elements
}
```

The code has been running for 40 minutes, but can not be completed.
How can i make execution faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `Person` implement `Comparable`?  If so, Groovy will be doing 1,046,089 operations.  If not, it will be taking the slower path and doing 34,000,000,000 operations ([see the code for minus here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L12662))

So you should be able to make it 34,000 times faster by making `Person` implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) Groovy will then use a TreeSet; add all of `listOne` to it, and then remove all of `listTwo`

If you can't make it comparable...  Hmmm...  Can you pre-sort the lists?

If so, we could maybe come up with an algorithm that walks both lists at the same time... and that *might* be quicker...

Comment: In ordinary Java, you would use `listOne.removeAll(new HashSet<>(listTwo))` doing it in `O(n)`. If you need a new list, prepend a `listOne = new ArrayList<>(listOne)`